# Basic questions about SNMP

Tags: network-protocols, snmp

I'm learning about SNMP, and writing some applications using it.  I have some basic questions about the protocol:

1. Do the agents store its state on the device itself?
2. If there is a trap set on an agent, can you do a poll on the same OID to get the same information?
3. Without using a mib file, is there a way to query a device for all of its information at once?  If not, and you're writing your own customized manager, do you have to know the structure of what it reports up front?
4. If you're setting up an agent to report, is there usually a way to control the frequency of how often it sends a trap?  Or does it usually send a trap as often as some condition is satisfied?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Do the agents store its state on the device itself?

You can store data on or off device. Both are possible and both are done. The problem with an agent storing (cached) state information about a remote device is that the management system never really knows if the (cached) data in the agent is acceptably up to date. If you cannot count on it, you'll need to use the manager to trigger a synchronization or to poll the state of the remote device and/or the communication link between the agent and the remote device. Once you get into that game, it is often better just to put a subagent on the remote device, and use standard SNMP protocols to get the information.

> If there is a trap set on an agent, can you do a poll on the same OID to get the same     information?

Most well-designed MIBs actually put the changed MIB object right into the trap. That way, your  SNMP Manager does not have to poll the agent just to be sure.

Having said that, the trap on the Entity-MIB does not have any state variables. However, that MIB is used to describe physical inventory such as shelves, cards, and ports, and the trap is thrown only if the physical configuration changes. In this case you are expected to have your SNMP Manager walk the Entity-MIB again to get the full new physical configuration.

> Without using a mib file, is there a way to query a device for all of its information at once?

Yes. Roll your own custom MIB and put whatever you want in it. You could put your entire device configuration into one MIB object. The down side of this is that you'll have to write a parser on your SNMP Manager to parse out the structure, and if the structure changes you'll need to figure out the meaning of the difference between the current value and the previous value. i.e. You'll re-invent some SNMP MIB. However, for very small MIBs, this might be worth doing.

You are probably better off using SNMP GET-BULK, or just doing a MIB walk by successively calling SNMP-GET-NEXT until no more objects are returned.

> If not, and you're writing your own customized manager, do you have to know the structure of what it reports up front?

If you want to keep your "customized manager" simple, you'll have to know the structure up front. If you want flexibility, you'll need structure-description language with which to encode your structure, and your manager will need to be able to decode this from the agent data and populate the manager, and take data from the manager and encode it in this format to send it to the agent(s). i.e. You'll re-invent SNMP/SMI, CMIP/CMISE, CIM, and a host of other management systems and protocols that have already been deployed.

> If you're setting up an agent to report, is there usually a way to control the frequency of how often it sends a trap? Or does it usually send a trap as often as some condition is satisfied?

This is a good question, because you often get a trap storm congesting your network precisely when you need your network the most. That makes it hard to predict how much network to provision.

Use traps judiciously. For example, the Entity-MIB only has one trap, and that one is worth using because it reports on physical structure changes. The Interfaces-MIB has potentially many traps per port. For this MIB, it is best just to enable traps for the interface bound to a physical port, and not for interfaces stacked on top of lower layer interfaces. For a large network, it is often best just to use a combination of polling plus traps for physical equipment and physical interfaces. That way, you can predict how much of your network will be used for management traffic whether during normal operation or during a network disaster.

Some standard MIBs specify how often or when you can throw a trap. If you are OK with that, then  use it. You can always roll your own Enterprise MIB with configuration MIB objects that let your manager throttle particular traps.

Answer (score 18):

> Do the agents store its state on the device itself?

In the most common scenario the SNMP agent is running on the device which monitors. In this case the agent has no other option and any state information must be stored on the device. SNMP agent just reads or sets these information.

> If there is a trap set on an agent,
>   can you do a poll on the same OID to
>   get the same information?

I think you should be able to do that - for example SNMPv2 trap IF-MIB::linkDown contains three varbinds - IF-MIB::ifIndex, IF-MIB::ifAdminStatus and IF-MIB::ifOperStatus. In this particular case the ifIndex specifies the row in the ifTable and other two can be polled.

> Without using a mib file, is there a
>   way to query a device for all of its
>   information at once?

Yes, use [`snmp-walk`](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/TUT:snmpwalk) from the net-snmp package or any other snmp tool that can use get-next to poll the data.

> If not, and you're writing your own
>   customized manager, do you have to
>   know the structure of what it reports
>   up front?

You do need to know what the device MIB contains - without such information you get only numeric OID and value, which is meaningless both for developers and users. In case of more complicated MIBs you need to know quite a lot of details about the managed device. MIB file hardly ever contains enough information.

Comment: Agree. In fact SNMP protocol does not cover all aspects David asked about. Many details such as state storage are implementation dependent. MIB documents open a door so that you can query information about a device, but its vendor always has better understanding of how to use the objects, as MIB documents usually do not cover all the details.

Answer (score -1):

> Do the agents store its state on the device itself?

It depends on the device and the application; some devices stores it locally others use a proxy agent.

> If there is a trap set on an agent, can you do a poll on the same OID to get the same information?

Yes, but it usually better to include information in the trap so the management station does not have to do multiple "round-trips" to the device. If you trap on an attribute value change, for instance, it is good practice to send the old and new value in the trap.

> Without using a mib file, is there a way to query a device for all of its information at once? If not, and you're writing your own customized manager, do you have to know the structure of what it reports up front?

Generally no... the SNMP Get-next primitive is designed for just such a case.

> If you're setting up an agent to report, is there usually a way to control the frequency of how often it sends a trap? Or does it usually send a trap as often as some condition is satisfied?

Yes, it is up to the agent on when to send traps.

If you are developing your own agent, I *highly* suggest you look at Net-SNMP. Even if you choose to go with another product, the Net-SNMP code is very well designed and implemented. Plus it has lots of extras to help develop and test agents (and management systems).

Comment: Copy and Paste? -1 as someone else used the same answer

Comment: Stack overflow novice mistake. Comment about NetSNMP should still be valid and useful.